# What is the equivalent for expression-bodied members in old C# versions?

Tags: c#, properties, getter, expression-bodied-members

In new versions of C# I have discovered recently that exist what is called expression-bodied-members as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

An example of expression-bodied-members would be (for a getter property only):

```
private int _x;
public int X
{
    get => _x;
}
```

Is above expression-bodied-member equivalent to below old C# versions?

```
private int _x;
public int X
{
    get
    {
       return _x;
    }
}
```

Comment: They aren't anything "new" - they've been around since C# 6.0 which was almost a decade ago.

Comment: Everytime you wonder whether a feature is compiled identically, just ask Sharplab https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxAvo0QA4BOAlgG4CGAFwCm6LgDsB6APoAPANysSoiegAaiJMQaatxAOZDJAXgB80+YpY6iaZZNUxFBa+gMCni4lADs5hS6tAoA==

Comment: @Martheen Great tool! a lot of thanks. I didn't know it. I will take into account from now on.

Comment: @Dai Ops, I didn't heard about it until just now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all equivalent:

```
private int _x;
public int X => _x;

private int _x;
public int X
{
    get => _x;
}

private int _x;
public int X
{
    get
    {
        return _x;
    }
}
```

Comment: And `public int X {get;}`

Comment: You're right, but only if you never use the _x field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these expressions are equivalent. Because expression-bodied-members do the same, but only for the single expression.

Comment: What do you mean when saying "but only for the single expression"?

Comment: I mean expression that contains only one line of code. You can put it to method without block of code.